# Selecting a div that are overlaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have side tabs that are overlaying. I want to be able to click one and do something with it, but I am having trouble getting my event handlers to register correct div.

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="blueTab">
    <div class="blueTab__container">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="brownTab">
    <div class="brownTab__container">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 853px;
}

.brownTab {
  position: absolute;
  .brownTab__container {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Fd49HkH.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    width: 400px;
    height: 853px;
  }
}

.blueTab {
  position: absolute;
  .blueTab__container {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/F5qg6xo.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    width: 400px;
    height: 873px;
  }
}

let brownTabElement = document.getElementsByClassName('brownTab')[0]
let blueTabElement = document.getElementsByClassName('blueTab')[0]


brownTabElement.addEventListener('click', brownTabHandler, false)

blueTabElement.addEventListener('click', blueTabHandler, false)

function brownTabHandler() {
    alert('brownTab')
}

function blueTabHandler() {
    alert('blueTab')
}
```

When ever I click both the blue or brown tab, only the event handler for the browntab gets called. How can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Le80rvL0/3/

Comment: Its because `brownTab` div is overlapping the `blueTab` div. So when ever you click on it, event Listener associated with `brownTab` is called.

Comment: They're set to the same dimensions and absolutely positioned.  The latter div with the brownTab class is "winning" because it occurs last in the markup.

Comment: Maybe you should not assign a classname as element to addeventlistener. Instead of that use document.addEventListener and also use event.target tk trigger them. Document is the higher layer generally if I get that right, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, even though you can see both tabs (because their backgrounds are partially transparent), the `.brownTab__container` element is overlapping the `.blueTab__container`, as they are in the exact same position, so you always click on that one. You can see that using the developer tools' inspector.

One solution to your problem would be to actually create different, non-overlapping elements that look like tabs. Maybe something like [this](https://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/) or like [this](https://shapeshed.com/overlapping-tabbed-navigation-in-css).

Another solution could be to use a single HTML element with a single background image of all the tabs, get the color of the clicked pixel and use it to distinguish the clicked tab. Something like this:

```js
const message = document.getElementById('message');

// Get the tabs element:
const tabs = document.getElementById('tabs');

// Get its computed styles:
const style = window.getComputedStyle(tabs);

// Extract the background-image's url:
const backgroundImage = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');
const url = backgroundImage.substring(5, backgroundImage.length - 2);

// Create an image with that url:
const img = document.createElement('IMG');
img.src = url;

// Create a canvas with the original size of the image:
const canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
const width = canvas.width = 1;
const height = canvas.height = 123;

//  Draw that image on it:
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

// Listen for click events:
document.getElementById('tabs').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // Get clicked pixel's RGBA value, taking into account the image on the tabs element is
  // repeated, while the one on the canvas it's not:
  
  const rgba = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX % width, e.offsetY % height, 1, 1).data;
  
  // Set color thresholds for each tab (as in your images the colors are not uniform as
  // they are here:
  
  if (rgba[2] > 200) {
    message.innerText = 'You clicked the blue tab.';
  } else if (rgba[2] < 150 && rgba[1] > 50) {
    message.innerText = 'You clicked the brown tab.';
  } else if (rgba[1] > 200) {
    message.innerText = 'You clicked the gold tab.';
  } else if (rgba[1] < 50) {
    message.innerText = 'You clicked the purple tab.';
  } else {
    message.innerText = 'Unknown tab clicked.';
  }
 
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 800px;
}

#message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 90px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#tabs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAB7CAYAAAC1rOouAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAqSURBVChTYzAOPfN/kBJnGtIGK/H+yYbBSpzRBjkSRNzUTkfmDhyR9h8AMPtPIMUTD3YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="tabs"></div>
```

Keep in mind that with the first approach it will be way easier to add other effects and features like hover/active/focus styles, add/remove tabs, move tabs, drag tabs...